# I need to get a list of users with a sum of pending orders amount in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel 5.4 app I created a while back. I need to add a functionality:

I need to fetch a list of users with a sum of pending orders amount.

```
name       |email       |pending_amount
user1_name |user1_email |1249
user2_name |user1_email |23424
```

I have these models

User.php

```
 ...
 public function orders()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'writer_id', 'id');
 }
 ...
```

Order.php

```
class Order extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'source_id',
        'client_id',
        'user_id',
        'status_id', // unpaid, pending or completed
        'title',
        'description',
        'amount',
        
    ];
```

This is what I have.

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $writers = User::whereHas("roles", function ($q) {
            $q->where("name", "customer")
                ->orWhere("name", "customer");
        })
        ->with("orders")
        ->get();
        return response()->json([
            'customers' => $customers
        ]);
```

The query above is providing all the orders that a user has, however I only need the total amount of pending orders from the orders table.

The end result should be something like this

[image: Expected result]

**Update**
This is what I have on the fetch query

```
<?
 
 

    $users = User::whereHas("roles", function ($q) {
                $q->where("name", "user")
                    ->orWhere("name", "users");
            })
            ->whereHas("orders", function($q) use($completed, $approved) {
                $q->where('status_id', $completed)
                    ->orWhere('status_id', $approved)
                    ->sum('amount');
            })
            ->get();
```

But am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(`amount`) as aggregate from `orders` where `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` and `status_id` = 9 or `status_id` = 6)
```

Comment: Check out the `->withCount()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models. The 2nd example there provides syntax for including a count of a relationship (`orders`, in your case), while also filtering them to a Status (`pending`, in your case). Try to implement that, and see what you can accomplish 

Comment: the 5.4 version of the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: You can define a relation `pendingOrders` and `whereHas('pendingOrders',fuction($query){
$query->sum('pending_amount'});`;

Comment: @TimLewis I do not need the count, I need sum of the amount column

Comment: fyi, there is [withSum](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withSum) in case someone looking for such function.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is the following

```
 $users = whereHas("roles", function ($q) {
                $q->where("name", "user")
                    ->orWhere("name", "users");
            })
            ->whereHas("orders", function($q) use($completed, $approved) {
                $q->where('status_id', $completed)
                    ->orWhere('status_id', $approved);
            })
        })->with('orders')->get();
```

And then make a calculated field in your user model class. like this

```
 private $pendingAmount


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPendingAmount()
    {
        return $this->pendingAmount;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $pendingAmount
     */
    public function setPendingAmount($pendingAmount)
    {
        $this->pendingAmount = $pendingAmount;
    }
    
    public function calcPendingAmount(){
        $this->pendingAmount = $this->orders()->sum('amount');
    }
```

Next, in the loop, calculate the sum for each user.

```
foreach($users as &$user){
     $user->calcPendingAmount();
  }
```

This field can be accessed using the get method

There is no function "withSum" in  laravel 5.4,like the latest versions of Laravel. therefore, either an additional loop or not use eloquent, but use DB facade and query builder.
[Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)